# How to show two different values of a list in Jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

the following code gives me two values. Either 97 or 12.

```
<form:input path="revRecov[${loop.index}].trkType" />
```

When it is 97 I want to use a label package and below the label I will be showing 4 rows.

When it is 12, I want to use a label Pallet and below the label I will be showing 4 rows. 
I will be showing both in the same screen at the same time.

Any suggestion on how to use it in a JSP is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you do that in controller and return the values you want to show?

Comment: I cannot do that in controller..I want to return both the values for 97 & 12 to same jsp from same list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `${loop.index}` I used 0 or 1. In this case as we are having only 2 rows, so we can pass the index directly instead of looping through.

```
 <tr><td>Package<form:input path="revRecov[0].trkType"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Pallet<form:input path="revRecov[1].trkType"/></td></tr>
```